# Call back for network connection present or not in windows mobile sdk?

Tags: windows, mobile

I use NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable in windows to check if internet access is avaiulable.

But in case of Windows Mobile development, this class is not available,

Please tell, how can i check if internet access is there or not.

Thanks,
Mrinal Jaiswal

Answer (score 0):

Check out [OpenNetCF's Smart Device Framework (SDF)](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx)

Documentation is [here](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/).